# Run npm install from parent folder on windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I have following project structure:

```
 -app
  -client
  -server
```

I need to run npm install from **server** folder (i have build script)
So i running

```
npm --prefix "../client" install
```

But instead of going to parent folder, npm creating folder with `..` **name** and **client** inside. And trying to run **`npm install`** there.  And installation fails because `package.json` is not there.

On linux its working fine.

How can i define relative path from parent folder ?